# Running a Django site on my local machine, am I redirecting my URLs properly?

Tags: django, apache

I am in the process of building a django website using Bitnami DjangoStack (includes, django, apache, and mySQL ) on my local windows 7 machine.

The project is called "MyProject"
At the moment my urls look like:
localhost/MyProject/
localhost/MyProject/login/
localhost/MyProject/admin/
etc. Whenever I redirect using HttpResponseRedirect('/login/') (which is what the tutorial I have been watching indicates I should do) I end up on "localhost/login" which does not work, so to rectify this I have been using HttpResponseRedirect('/MyProject/login/') instead, which does work.

I want my finished project to be on "http://www.MyProject.com", and have pages like www.MyProject.com/login, but the way I seem to have it configured I will end up with "www.SomeDomain.com/MyProject/login". Is HttpResponseRedirect('/MyProject/login/')  valid for what I want to do, or should I configure my settings.py to something different? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should not hard code url strings in Django code (neither templates nor views) but use the [Django URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#examples)

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #...
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
    #...
)
```

views.py

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news.views.year_archive', args=(year,)))
```

To address your problem, your main urls.py can wrap your other project urls like following, that will prepend SITE_BASE_URL to all our included project urls.

```
SITE_BASE_URL = '/MyProject/' 
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... snip ...
    url(r'{site_base}'.format(site_base=SITE_BASE_URL), include('project.urls')),
    # ... snip ...
)
```

Now you simply can make "SITE_BASE_URL" environment specific. You can use settings file (can keep different for production or local environments) or pass it as an environment variable from Apache itself, Ref: http://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2010/nov/12/apache-environment-variables-and-mod_wsgi/.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, I was just wondering if you could elaborate slightly on your last step, is what I am essentially doing adding the '/MyProject/' to the start of each url in urls.py using the SITE_BASE_URL variable? To configure it will I follow the directions in your link and replace "APP_DATABASE_NAME appdb" with SITE_BASE_URL /MyProject/? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you can prepend it to all URLS. Or a better solution is to define it just once like I mentioned above and use a wrapper. You are correct Re: the Apache configuration, replace it with SITE_BASE_URL /MyProject/ in your LAMP environment and  SITE_BASE_URL / on your production environment once you change the domain.